# UpdatePanel не обновляется обратно

Tags: c#, asp.net

В форме есть `DropDownList` и `CheckBoxList`
Значение в `DropDownList` должен меняться в зависимости от выбора `CheckBoxList`
Поместил оба элемента в `UpdatePanel`.
 Значение в `DropDownList` меняется при выборе(клике) элемента, а если снять отметку обратно не меняется(остается как высокий)
**aspx:**

```
 Риск:
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpRisk" runat="server" UpdateMode="always">
 <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRiskLevel" runat="server" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Низкий" Value="1" Selected="True" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Высокий" Value="2" />
   </asp:DropDownList>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel24" runat="server" UpdateMode="always">
   <ContentTemplate>
         Признаки:
      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chbList_Risks" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem> признак1 </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem> признак2 </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem> признак3 </asp:ListItem>
      </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Код:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ListItem item in chbList_Risks.Items)
   {
       if (item.Selected)
        ddlRiskLevel.SelectedValue = "2";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вариант "высокий" должен выбираться, если отмечен хотя бы один чекбокс, иначе выбирается "низкий":

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlRiskLevel.SelectedValue = "1";
    foreach (ListItem item in chbList_Risks.Items) {
        if (item.Selected)
            ddlRiskLevel.SelectedValue = "2";
    }
}
```

Для элемента `chbList_Risks` также установите свойство `AutoPostBack` в `True`:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chbList_Risks" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
```